# Integrate jquery ajax form and json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, xpath

I'm beginer to web developing so maybe this is a so easy and stupid question from my side but I tring to find a way to solve this all day and please HELP.

I have a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.style1 {font-size: 24px};
-->
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:600px;
    height:1000px;
    margin-top:50px; 
    background:url(bgMob.jpg);
    border:solid;
    border-color:#CCCCCC;
    }
#inside {
    width:920px;
    height:1500px;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
    }
.style2 {color: #CC0000}
.style4 {color: #FF6600}
.style5 {color: #FF0000}
.styleField {
    border-radius:5px;
    border-width:thin;
    border-color:#CCCCCC;
    height:30px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:16px;
    }
.styleField:hover {
    background:#CC0000;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    }
.styleButton {
    background:#EEEEEE;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-width:thin;
    border-color:#CCCCCC;
    height:30px;
    }
    .styleButton:hover {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    }
</style></head>

<body>

<div align="center" class="style1 style2"><span class="style5">creator</span><span class="style4"></span></div>
<div id="wrapper"><div id="inside">
    <form id="city" name="city" action="<?php echo $_POST["city"]; ?>" method="post">
    <label>CITY name :<br /> 
      <input name="city" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <label>
    <input name="city" type="submit"  class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
    </label>
  </form>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>Enter the site URL:<br /> 
      <input name="textfield" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <label>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
    </label>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form0" name="form0" method="post" action="">
    <label>Enter the  URL where is all deals:<br /> 
    <input name="textfield0" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <label>
    <input name="Submit0" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
    </label>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location of links where is ALL deals<br />
    <input name="textfield2" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location of TITLE <br />
    <input name="textfield3" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit3" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form33" name="form33" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location of SUB-TITLE <br />
    <input name="textfield33" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit33" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location of PRICE <br />
    <input name="textfield4" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit4" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location of Original PRICE <br />
    <input name="textfield5" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit5" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form6" name="form6" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location of DISSCOUNT <br />
    <input name="textfield6" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit6" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form7" name="form7" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location of MAP - latitude, longitude <br />
    <input name="textfield7" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit7" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form8" name="form8" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location offer TIME <br />
    <input name="textfield8" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit8" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form9" name="form9" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Xpath location of BUSINESS name <br />
    <input name="textfield9" type="text" class="styleField" size="50" />
    </label>
    <input name="Submit9" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Check!" />
  </form>
  <hr />
  <form id="form10" name="form10" method="post" action="">
    <label>
      <div align="center">
        <input name="Submit10" type="submit" class="styleButton" value="Create a scraping file!" />
    </div>
    </label>
  </form>
  <hr />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have a second php file who i want to execute with jquery and based on entered xpath in form...

here is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>Scraping - eKupon.ba</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>

<body>



<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('../includes/php.scarping.php');





//Adresa sajta

$scrapeConf['homePage']             = 'http://www.ekupon.ba';



//Adresa gdje se nalaze sve ponude

$scrapeConf['mainURL']              = 'http://www.ekupon.ba/aktivne-ponude/';



//XPATH putanja do linkova od svake ponude ponaosob

$scrapeConf['PonudaLinkovi']        = "//div[@class='pdodatna-naslovbox']/a/@href";



//XPath Putanja do naslova ponude

$scrapeConf['PonudaNaslov']         = "//div[@id='naslovbox']/span[@class='naslov']";



//XPath Putanja do podnaslova ponude

$scrapeConf['PonudaPodnaslov']      = "//div[@id='naslovbox']/span[@class='podnaslov']";



//XPath Putanja do prve slike koju zelimo

$scrapeConf['PonudaSlika']          = "//*[@id='ponuda']//a/img/@src";



//XPath putanja do polja sa cijenom

$scrapeConf['PonudaCijena']         = "//*[@id='ponuda']//div[@class='cijena']";



//XPath putanja do polja sa orginalnom cijenom

$scrapeConf['PonudaOrgCijena']      = "//*[@id='podaci']//span";



//XPath putanja do polja sa orginalnom cijenom

$scrapeConf['PonudaPopust']         = "//table[@id='podaci']//tr[2]/td[2]/span";



//Xpath do dijela koji sadrzi ili <script> sa lat lng ili url sa lat|lng

$scrapeConf['PonudaLatLng']         = "//table[@id='lokacija']//td/script[2]";



//Xpath putanja do elementa koji sadrzi vrijeme do istka ponude

$scrapeConf['PonudaVaziDo']         = "//table[@class='sjena']//span[@class='sat']";



//Xpath putanja do dijela koji sadrzi ime firme (nije obavezno)

$scrapeConf['PonudaFirmaIme']       = "//table[@id='lokacija']//p/strong";



//Xpath putanja do dijela koji sadrzi adresu firme (nije obavezno)

$scrapeConf['PonudaFirmaAdresa']    = "";



//Xpath putanja do dijela koji sadrzi telefon  (nije obavezno)

$scrapeConf['PonudaFirmaTel']       = "";



//Xpath putanja do dijela koji sadrzi email  (nije obavezno)

$scrapeConf['PonudaFirmaMail']      = "";





//Uzmi sve ponude

$ponudeList = xpathPonude($scrapeConf);



//DODAVANJE PONUDA

foreach ($ponudeList as $key => $ponuda) {

    //OVDE obraditi varijable iz ponuda ako ima potrebe...

    $ponuda['naslov']    = str_replace(' -', '', $ponuda['naslov']);

        //sacuvaj sliku

        $imeSlike = date('YMDHM-') . $ponuda['lat'] .'.jpg';

        save_image($ponuda['slika'], '/home/pluspon/public_html/slike/'. $imeSlike);

        $ponuda['slika'] = $imeSlike;







    //  DO OVE LINIJE SVE PONUDE I VARIJABLE MORAJU BITI

    //  SREDJENE I SPREMNE ZA UPIS U BAZU

    print insertNew($ponuda['naslov'], $ponuda['podnaslov'], $ponuda['lat'], $ponuda['lng'], $ponuda['slika'], $ponuda['url'], $ponuda['popust'], $ponuda['vaziDo'], $ponuda['firma'], $ponuda['firmaadresa'], $ponuda['firmaemail'], $ponuda['firmatelefon'], $ponuda['firmaURL']);

}



//Debug vreme

print 'Vreme proteklo '. sk_genTime() .' sekundi';

?>

</body>

</html>
```

also what I want is when user type xpath in form and click on check then get a $result from php file and know is the xpath right or not. Offcource the result print right on the button. I know that can do it with ajax and jquery but I'm not very well in this so I also want to pay to someone who want to help me. And really sorry for my english but I'm working now on my engslih hard.

also I need to replace a text in apostrof (') with value from form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onSubmit parameter to the form tag, which calls a JavaScript function. That JavaScript function should call the PHP script by using the JQuery post function, and passing it the form data. The success callback of the post function will receive the data returned by the PHP script, and you can put that anywhere on your calling page via the DOM.

Comment: Do I need for every check button a new function or how it works? becouse when i click on check i want to get only one part from php. example. title or sometnig else ponuda['image'] etc